# Wordpress - is it possible when viewing posts on a specific category to not show the most recent three posts?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have a link to view posts in a certain category:

```
 <?php
    // Get ID of category
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'Video' );

    // Get URL of category
    $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
    ?>

   <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" title="Category Name">&laquo; View Previous</a>
```

In my category.php I need to tell it to ignore the most recent three posts of the category it is displaying.  I can get it to ignore the first three posts with something like this:

```
<?php query_posts('cat='.$cat_ID.'&showposts=3&offset=-3'); ?>
```

But that seems to just have it display all categories (less newest three posts). In other words, it no longer just shows posts from the 'video' category or 'news' category. I need it to detect what category it is displaying and remove the newest three from that.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?php

    $cat_array[] = get_cat_ID( 'Video' );
   $cat_array[] = get_cat_ID( 'News' );

    if(in_array( $cat_ID, $cat_array))
     query_posts('cat='.$cat_ID.'&showposts=3&offset=-3'); 
    else
     query_posts('cat='.$cat_ID); 
    ?>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I'd be hard coding the category.  Thus, if I link to another category, say News, won't this show Videos?  Is there way to do this that doesn't require a hard coded value for the category ID?  If I send a user to /category/video/ it knows which categories to pull.

Actually - there is a limited number of categories, maybe I can just  add the other to this.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how to do this.  How could I add the news category to this?  I assume perhaps another if statement?

Comment: what you really want to achieve ?

Comment: I want any category page to not show the newest three posts.  Right now I only have Video and News as categories. So, anytime a user goes to mysite/category/video/ the newest three videos won't appear.  Same for mysite/category/news/.  I don't know how to add the news category to your solution above.  Thanks!